# Libusb interrupt transfer callback

Tags: c, winapi, libusb

I'am working on a real-time control system that calculates the control signals in a buffered fashion (a user-mode program) and outputs to the usb device the array through isochronous transfers. The usb device them reports the execution progress through interrupt transfer, so that pc software can then calculate and push the next control array.

The software runs based on raw win32 api, C based. (C++ used only on not time sensitive parts of the program, such as interface, 3D models...).

I would like to know if there is a way to register a callback function in response to a interrupt transfer?

Comment: You might read [here](http://libusb.sourceforge.net/api-1.0/group__asyncio.html#ga62afeef38ae1003e14d2e8eb06462f25).

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, although we are talking about *interrupt* transfers, the USB device still has to be *polled* using libusb_interrupt_transfer:

> Interrupt transfers are typically non-periodic, small device
>   "initiated" communication requiring bounded latency. An Interrupt
>   request is queued by the device until the host polls the USB device
>   asking for data.

Excerpt from https://www.beyondlogic.org/usbnutshell/usb4.shtml#Interrupt